# Using Spam Assassin as email proxy

Tags: linux, spamassassin, spam-filter, spam

I'm looking to setup a Spam Filter Proxy for my clients, not too many mind you, and have it as transparent as possible.

I read about SAVASM and Spam Vigilante, and while they are perfect I guess for the job, I can't install them directly to the intended Cloud VM.

I figure Spam Assasin is the way to go and would like to deploy it myself, or learn how to, as it will be on a Linux Cloud VM.

The OS it will be going onto is CentOS - does anyone have any better suggestions as to waht OS flavour they think this should go on?

Also does anyone know of any well rounded resources or how to guides to go about this?

While I know it isn't recommended to block 'bad' email outright, unless there is some kind of web portal I can have the clients log in to to check blocked email, I would have to have the system store the 'bad' email for x many days should the clients come looking for it.

Also is it possible, with Spam Assassin, to forward on to different SMTP servers depending on the mail domain it is intended for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to ask for how to guides - you should not be doing this for any "clients". From your question it seems you do not understand what [spamassassin](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/) is or how it works.

It is a `milter` (mail filter). The messages to check for SPAM get passed to it by your [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent). How to configure it properly depends on the MTA you use.

Comment: While I agree with your statement, I have to be perfectly frank - sometimes a gentle nudge in the right direction will help people find the track to their end goal. At the time I didn't realise exactly what it was I was asking for... but I knew what it was that I wanted to accomplish. I have since accomplished my goals and am a great deal more knowledgeable in the area, and also know the correct lingo to be using. Please, in future, offer useful answers, or help people along the way - don't prompt them to not climb the wall so-to-speak.